# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection ')) in python request.api

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests

resp = requests.api.post(url,headers=self.headers,data=json.dumps(data))
```

when running it in jenkins, it is working fine sometimes, but in others it is throwing below error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: I had the exact same error before! I think it might be the server?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.post()` call is correct.

The server is broken and/or your data is not well formed so it causes the server to exhibit broken behavior. (I would expect a `400` or `500` from the server.)

Verify that TCP/IP connectivity is good, e.g. with `$ telnet host 443`.

Verify that `data` is of sane length -- sending gigabytes wouldn't make you happy.

EDIT

Now you're saying it is deterministic behavior: 1st works, 2nd fails.
This suggests that connection caching is relevant.
The requests module maintains a pool of open TCP connections to webservers, in case another request arrives soon.

Perhaps you POSTed, server said `201` Created or whatever,
and *also* said that client should close the connection upon reading status.
But client didn't close connection,
and is surprised to find the server end is closed when attempting 2nd POST over same connection.

You are running:

```
resp = requests.api.post(url, ...)
```

You could instead use:

```
sess = requests.Session()
resp = sess.post(url, ...)
```

Then you'd have control over when to discard the session connection pool and make a new one.

Comment: but it works fine for the same data once and gives connection aborted other time.

Comment: i have implemented this but still i was facing the above issue of connection aborted, is there any other way to overcome

Comment: You have not yet identified why the Server behaves as it does. Without diagnosing the root cause, making random changes to Client behavior is unlikely to improve matters. Crank up the log level on both ends. Use wireshark to view http details.